# Want to get content of a span on amazon.de

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will get a the text of a span on https://www.amazon.de/

I tried like that

```
$('.a-spacing-top-extra-large:first').text();
```

and much other things, but every time i get this error.

```
VM186:211 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.a-spacing-top-extra-large:first' is not a valid selector.(…)
```

I tried much things, with jquery or javascript but all the time same error. 
On other sites this code works

I know that there are other guys who have a worked code but i dont find a way...

I want to get it with jquery or javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon doesn't use the jQuery library which is why your script is not working.

If you wanted to select that node using plain JavaScript you would use something like this `document.getElementsByClassName("a-spacing-top-extra-large")[0].textContent`

Answer (score 0):

If you use this,

```
$('.a-spacing-top-extra-large:first-child').text();
```

you should get the value you want.

You are nearly there with your selector, but it should be `:first-child`